# MySQL type CHAR problem in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-relations

They say, if you want to find the answer, ask the right question. Really, here I don't know what to ask. Because I don't know what's happening.

Migration:create_table1_table

```
$table->char('code', 1)->primary();
$table->string('name', 50);
```

I seeded the database and the following is a sample:

```
code: d
name: district
```

In tinker:

```
$t1 = Table1::find('d');
```

returns:

```
=>App\Models\Table1 {#3249                                
      code: "d",         
      name: "district",
  }
```

Here where I cannot understand:

```
$t1->code; //returns 0 <---This should be 'd'
$t1->name; //returns district
```

This causes my model which has a hasMany(Table2::class, 't1_pk') relationship with table2 to not work correctly:

```
public function table2 () {
    return $this->hasMany(Table2::class, 't1_pk');
}
```

Then:

```
$t1->table2()->toSql();
```

Returns:

```
select * from `table2` where `table2`.`t1_pk` = ? and `table2`.`t1_pk` is not null

//Here the foreign key "table2.t1_pk" that must be matched with the value of "table1.code = 'd'" changes to ? (anything).
```

What so far I understood column 'code' type juggles to integer:

```
getType($t1->code); //returns Integer
```

What is going on here and how to make laravel's Eloquent hasMany() to generate a correct query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast your custom primary key to the correct type and ensure that Eloquent doesn't think that your primary key is auto incrementable:

```php
class Table1 extends Model { 

    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $casts = [
        'code' => 'string'
    ];

...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Repox for the amazing help. Problem solved.

In additon to Repox's solution, I also added:
    protected $keyType = 'string';